# How to upload video files in tinymce editor

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tinymce

I want to add functionality of uploading video in tinymce editor in nextjs but the only option I can see is pasting youtube video links.

here is my component

Inside editor init, I am using these plagins and toolbar

```
plugins: [
            `lists ${!props.isAdminPanel && 'image'} wordcount`,
            'code fullscreen',
            'autolink',
            'link',
            'media',
            'mediaembed'
          ],
```

toolbar:
'undo redo | formatselect | image | anchor | bold italic backcolor | 
alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | 
bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | 
table | media | video_upload',

Images upload handler:

```
images_upload_handler: props.imageUploadHandler,
videos_upload_handler: props.videoUploadHandler,
```

the image upload is as I expect
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hr4Z.png)
but for video upload I can't see the button option for upload. Is there any way to do it?